# Accessing MySQL on remote machine

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have remote machine, where a MySQL instance is running.
I'm looking for a small open source/free application, which does the following:

- runs on the remote machine
- connects to MySQL
- can be accessed through http (with a browser)
- written in Java
- without installing anything

Basicly I need something like PHP MyAdmin, without Apache, and written in Java.

Can anybody suggest something simmilar?

Comment: It may also help us if you explain why it needs to be written in Java...

Comment: I would like to use this on varius enviroments - Win, Linux -, and a universal solution would be nice :-)

Comment: Both PHP and Apache meet that criteria.

Comment: Why don't you just use MySql GUI tools, so you can remotely run a MySql Administrator remote instance? (It has actually been superseeded by MySql Workbench)

Comment: As far as I know, both PHP and Apache are needed to be installed - or at least are too "heavyweight" for what I'm lookgin for. I just need an application, that I can copy and start at the desired location - no installing, no - advanced - configuraiton ...

Comment: @krisy: you just need to install PHP MyAdmin and the Apache server at one location (i.e machine1), the other users can access via browser to the admin console on this machine, without any aditional instalation (i.e at their browser 'http:/ /machine1/phpMyAdmin' )

Comment: @OP Have you tried installing [MySql GUI tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) / [MySql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) on your client machine?

Answer (score 1):

You could try SQuirreL: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/
It supports out-of-the-box different DB engines (MySql, Oracle, PostgreSQL...). For MySQL specific functions, you could also dowload an aditional plugin.

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement: "can be accessed through http (with a browser)"

Comment: +1 SquirrelSQL is a wonderful tool, I use it all the time as my UI of choice for DB access and administration.

Comment: @ziesemer: ups. That's true. But then, I don't understand the need of a cross-platform client: with a single instalation the other users could just access through the MyAdmin writing the URL at their browser. ??

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use [MySql GUI tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html), so you can remotely run MySql Administrator and MySql Query Browser remote instances?

(For the newest MySql versions, MySql GUI tools has actually been superseeded by [MySql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/))

Answer (score 0):

You should used mysql query browser [click here to download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)

Comment: I need a solution, which is accessible from the browser :-(